# How to choose random numbers generator in Python

Tags: python, random

I have a task to compare 2 random numbers generators (any of them). Generator should be able to produce values according to given distribution.

I went to numpy docs, there is only option to seed generator, same with scipy and standard lib.

So, what is there a library where I would be able to choose engine?

Comment: A [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (as an example of a bad pseudo-random number generator) is very easy to write.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I forgot to mention that engine should be able to generate values according to a distribution, so library would fit my needs better. Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest solution:

```
>>> from random import random
>>> random()
0.4060522793588409
```

which is implemented as the Mersenne Twister (and therefore deterministic) and

```
>>> from random import SystemRandom
>>> gen = SystemRandom()
>>> gen.random()
0.5496630511131738
```

which is OS based (and non-deterministic hence different from the Marsenne Twister). No libs needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not exactly what I need. Please, look at updated question.

Comment: @gasabr You achieve any distribution by applying [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) on a uniform distribution.

Comment: did not know about it. Thanks!

Comment: @gasabr Also read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling